# Reachability problems in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, reachability

I have been trying to check for internet connectivity. If the device is connected to the internet then it goes to initial viewController on MainStoryboard otherwise it shows another viewController on the same storyboard. But this code doesn't work for me. I don't get any errors, it just doesn't work.

Here is the Screenshot:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xvNI.png)

And here is what I wrote in AppDelegate.swift:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var reachability: Reachability?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ReachabilityCheck(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.reachabilityChanged, object: nil)
    return true
}
```

And the function is:

```
    @objc func ReachabilityCheck(_: Notification) {
    var remoteHostStatus = self.reachability!.currentReachabilityStatus()

    if remoteHostStatus == NotReachable
    {
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let offlineViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "notReachable") as! notReachableViewController
        window!.rootViewController = offlineViewController
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }else
    {
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainNav") as! UINavigationController
        window!.rootViewController = initialViewController
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

What should I do to make it work? Please help!

Comment: Where do you set the `reachability` property? And please conform to the naming convention. Classes / structs start with an uppercase, variables and functions / methods with a lowercase letter.

Comment: I have downloaded the property from Apple: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: No, `var reachability: Reachability?` is declared but not initialized. The property is `nil`. To monitor the reachability you have to initialize a `Reachability` instance and assign it to the property. At the moment the code does nothing.

Comment: I initialised that like `self.reachability = Reachability.forInternetConnection()
        self.reachability?.startNotifier()` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions` in **AppDelegate.swift** But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you saying you want to go to the initial view controller when the app starts and it has a connection and if it has no connection it goes to a different controller or do you want to continually monitor the status and change if the devices loses connection?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth I indeed want to keep monitoring but also want to display a different viewController if there is no connection.

Comment: First the issue at hand and it could be the code for your Reachability class has a problem so I think you need to post that.  Secondly there is a problem with your approach in that if the connection is lost then you are changing the root view controller of the app so you will lose everything the user is currently doing which is not a good user experience.  If your app really has to stop right then when the connection is lost it would be better to present some kind of modal view controller so that you can easily restore everything when the connection is back.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4

Create a new Swift class

```
import Foundation

import Alamofire

class Connectivity {

class func isConnectedToInternet() ->Bool {

return NetworkReachabilityManager()!.isReachable

}

}
```

// usage.....

```
    if Connectivity.isConnectedToInternet() == true {
            print("Yes! internet is available.")
            // do some tasks..
        }
        else
        {
           // self.view.makeToast("Yes! internet is available.")
            print("Yes! internet is available.")
        }
```